# SSIS Fails to retrieve the provider invariant name & Error 0xC020844C

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

SSIS Catalog Package. Works on development computer fails on server Microsoft SQL server 2014, Windows 2012R2.

**2 Main Errors**

> Failed to retrieve the provider invariant name for System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, it is not currently supported by ADO NET Destination component.
>
> Failed to get properties of external columns the table name you entered may not exist ....

I think the first error is causing the 2nd error. Although it works fully on development computer. It is not a 32bit vs 64bit problem because I toggled the option and tried for both options in SSIS Job.

[image]

Comment: what is the difference between the 2014 server vs 2012 in regards to `TCP/IP || NamePipes` are the both configured the same..? also take a look at this article as well https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/docast/2014/10/24/tips-and-tricks-to-fix-sql-connectivity-issues/

Comment: Simple question, maybe there is no odbc drivers on server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obdc driver fails on server. But OLE db source driver works.

For whatever reason.